# Tiered Case Priority and Response Time Formula

Tags: formula, case, formula-field, image-formula, nested

I have a formula to measure SLA response times, however it doesn't seem to be filtering based on priority as it's intended. It only seems to filter as if Priority is Low on the case, or just always shows Green.

```
CASE(Priority,
'High', IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 10
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20),
IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c > 5
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif","Yellow",20,20),
IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c <= 3
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif","Green",20,20),null
)
)
)
,
'Medium', IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 30
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20),
IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c > 7
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif","Yellow",20,20),
IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c <= 7
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif","Green",20,20),null
)
)
)
,
'Low', IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 60
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20),
IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c > 30
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif","Yellow",20,20),
IF(
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c)),
First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c <= 10
),
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif","Green",20,20),null
)
)
),
null
)
```

Please advise!

Comment: Can you post the details of the record the formula is evaluating? TTR_Snapshot, First_Response_Time_Minutes__c, Priority values?

Comment: TTR_Snapshot__c is a DateTime field, First_Response_Time_Minutes__c is a formula that calculates the time from open -> first status change in minutes, Priority is Case Priority.

Basically, Case Priority is set based on Account's SLA_Priority automagically (workflow rule), and with each SLA priority (Low, Med, Hi) there's different response times required. So I need it to calculate response performance per priority tier.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough, need the values in those field for the record where you are saying the formula is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I see in your formula is that you have gaps where color is not assigned at all (e.g. when `Priority` is 'Low' and `First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c` > 10 and <=30) - I don't believe this is how Performance wanted to be tracked. I tweaked the formula and simplified it to where the only values has to be set are threshold for 'Red' and 'Yellow' (inclusive), all numbers below would be Green. Also, indicator will be not shown if `TTR_Snapshot__c` is blank.

> - High: Green < 5, Yellow >= 5, Red >=10
> - Medium: Green < 7, Yellow >= 7,> Red >=30
> - Low: Green < 30, Yellow >= 30, Red >=60

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c),
    NULL,
    IF(
        First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 
            CASE(Priority,
                'High', 10,
                'Medium', 30,
                60 /* 'Low' */
                ),
        IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20),

    IF(
    First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 
        CASE(Priority,
            'High', 5,
            'Medium', 7,
            30 /* 'Low' */
            ),
    IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif","Yellow",20,20),

    IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif","Green",20,20)
    )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your formula to a more cleaner format:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c) &&
CASE(Priority,
    'High', 
    IF(
        First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 10,
        IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20),
        IF(
            First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c > 5,
            IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif","Yellow",20,20),
            IF(
                First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c <= 3,
                IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif","Green",20,20),
                null
            )
        )
    ),
    'Medium', 
    IF(
        First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 30,
        IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20),
        IF(
            First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c > 7,
            IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif","Yellow",20,20),
            IF(
                First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c <= 7,
                IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif","Green",20,20),
                null
            )
        )
    ),
    'Low', 
    IF(
        First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c >= 60,
        IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20),
        IF(
            First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c > 30,
            IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif","Yellow",20,20),
            IF(
                First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c <= 10,
                IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif","Green",20,20),
                null
            )
        )
    ),
    null
)
```

There were no other issues with the formula. Therefore, the only troubleshooting I can suggest is to check the values of the `**First_Response_Time_Minutes_hidden__c**` field and it's impact on the color of the image.

Comment: The combination of `NOT(ISBLANK(TTR_Snapshot__c) &&` and `IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif","Red",20,20)` as particular result (or any other) of `CASE` function doesn't make any sense

Comment: That's correct, I made a mistake there. Thanks for pointing it out :)